# SwiftのGenerics型の命名規則の由来

Tags: swift, java, 命名規則

[SwiftのGenerics型の命名規則](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID183)について読んでいて思ったのですが、
この命名規則の由来の大元は[JavaのGenerics型の命名規則](http://java.keicode.com/lang/generics-naming.php)からきているのでしょうか？

SwiftとJavaの関係がよく分からないので、
Swift側の”伝統的な〜"がJavaを指しているのか確認できたら嬉しいです。
(何も考えずにT,U,Vつければ事足りはするのですが…Generics型ってJavaから出てきたもの？)

Comment: 少なくともC++の方が先ですね

Comment: GenericsはAdaなどまでさかのぼれるらしいです。命名は各言語で、単語・1文字・Tプレフィックス付き単語などあるらしく、それぞれの言語の命名規則をまとめると関係が見えてくるかもしれませんね。

Comment: 思ったよりも歴史のある命名規則で驚きましたが、Swift自身もObjective-Cと互換があったり、記述方法などCの系譜に近いところがあるので特に何かを指して”こういうルールだから”と言うわけでもなく昔から（それこそ伝統的に）使われてきたからそうしなさいと言う感じですね。(Tからと言うのも意味のあるものとブツからない、アルファベット順の後ろの方だからU,Vと続けられるとか色々あるようですが…）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

特にJavaからというわけでもなく、古い言語だとAdaなどでも使われていたようです。
由来の大元が分からないほど昔から伝統的に使われている命名規則のようなので、
諸説ある理由から納得出来るものを飲み込んで置いて、慣例に習い命名しておきたいと思います。
(アルファベット順の後ろの方だから意味のあるものとブツかりにくい、U,V‌​と続けられるなど…）